# GUI elements shifted with MS Outlook 11.0 Object Library + Outlook 2016 Ver 1702

Tags: windows, email, user-interface, outlook, email-attachments

I've an proprietary software with own IDE and windows client. In the IDE I use the `Microsoft Outlook 11.0 Object Library` to send attachments per Mail. But since `Outlook 2016` `Version 1702` the GUI elements To, Cc and subject are shifted. The Sendbutton is also not reachable. In `Version 1609` I didn't have the problem. Does anybody know this problem and how to fix it? Is there maybe a newer version of the library? Or is there a setting in `Outlook` which solves the problem? Thanks in advance.

[image: new mail with shifted to, Cc and subject]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered this issue and can confirm it has started occurring as of Office 2016 update 1701. It does not appear to be related to the object library as I am using the 16.0 object library, not 11.0.

I managed to narrow down the GUI issue (as depicted in the image you posted) to file attachments.

To address this issue, **display the mail window first and then attach any files**. Here is an example of the approach I took:

```
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim exampleMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim exampleFiles As Outlook.Attachments

Set exampleMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set exampleFiles = exampleMail.Attachments

With exampleMail
    .To = "example@email.com"
    .Subject = "Example Subject"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "Hello, This is an example."
    .Display
End With

Filename = "C:\SomeFolder\someFile.xlsx"
exampleFiles.Add Filename
```

If you are choosing to late-bind:

```
Dim olApp As Object   
Dim exampleMail As Object
Dim exampleFiles As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set exampleMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
Set exampleFiles = exampleMail.Attachments
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion and it seems like it has done the trick. Thanks a lot. I'll wait for a few days if I hear of any complaints and report back